# Universal Property Of $\text{Bilin}(A,A',-):\text{Ab}\to\text{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

In class, we had to state the universal property of $\text{Bilin}(A,A',-):\text{Ab}\to\text{Set}$, the functor taking an abelian group $B$ to the set of bilinear maps $f:U(A)\times U(A')\to U(B)$ where $U:\text{Ab}\to\text{Set}$ is the forgetful functor.  This was the solution given (under the assumption that some representing object $A\otimes A'$ of $\text{Bilin}(A,A',-)$ exists):

> Let $\alpha:H^{A\otimes A'}\cong\text{Bilin}(A,A',-)$ be the isomorphism relating the representing object to the functor.  Define $\tau:=\alpha(A\otimes A')(\text{id}_{A\otimes A'})$, then for all $X\in\text{Ab}_0$ and $g\in\text{Bilin}(A,A',X)$ there exists a unique $\bar{g}\in\text{Ab}(A\otimes A',X)$ such that $g=(\text{Bilin}(A,A',-)(\bar{g}))(\tau)$.

My question: how exactly is this a universal property?  nLab states that a universal property boils down to the object (or something closely associated) is initial in an appropriate auxiliary category.

What I could imagine is that this means we look at the category of dependent pairs $(X,g)\in\sum_{\text{Ab}_0}\text{Bilin}(A,A',X)$ with morphisms $\bar{f}:(X,g)\to (Y,f\circ g)$ for any $f:X\to Y$ (is there some fancy description of this construct, maybe in terms of comma categories?) and then $(A\otimes A',\tau)$ is initial.

But what interests me now, and maybe this is completely obvious, but is $\text{Bilin}(A,A',-)$ also initial in it's own isomorphism class in $[\text{Ab},\text{Set}]$?

I'm sorry if this all is just confused gibberish.  Sometimes category theory blurs my thinking way too much.

Comment: This is the universal property of the tensor product, not of $\mathrm{Bilin}$. While the description of $A\otimes A'$ is correct, and you're proving that it's the initial object of the category of elements of $\mathrm{Bilin}$, your question about initiality of $\mathrm{Bilin}$ itself doesn't make sense: if one element of an isomorphism class is initial, so are all the others, because there must be a unique map between all of them. I don't know of a natural universal problem solved by $\mathrm{Bilin}$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thanks for your answer!  I see your point in 'if one element of an isomorphism class is initial, so are all the others', but how can I prove that all the other elements are initial (if they are)?  Also, I feel like the definition of universal property is a bit vague, e.g. the universal property of the product $X\times Y$ in $C$ is a terminal object in $(\Delta\downarrow(X,Y))$, but it is not the object $X\times Y\in C_0$ per se rather than some object we *recognize* being essentially $X\times Y$.

Comment: Being initial is invariant under isomorphism. I don't understand your second comment.